# Vcpkg Libraries not detected by Visual Studio 2019 Community edition

Tags: visual-studio-2019, vcpkg

I am currently working on a Open-Source Project, which has some third-party library dependencies, I have installed all of them using Vcpkg into a particular folder in my E: drive and integrated them with Visual Studio with the "vcpkg integrate install" command, and supplied the Cmake toolchain also in the IDE.

But the libraries (ie. WxWidgets currently) are not being detected while configuring the build.

I am attaching the configuration message as well as the error snapshots below.

Any suggestions regarding this, would of great help.

Thanks & Regards.

[buildsnap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caByD.png)
[ErrorSnap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsF03.png)

Comment: please attach the error screenshots/snapshots.

Comment: Sorry for the error, due some error the snapshots were not uploaded, now i have edited the post and posted two snapshots, of the build configure messages and the error also